# How to verify that IntentionAction was called on an interface file? IntelliJ Platform SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new in the IntelliJ Platform SDK and a plugin development.

I want to implement [IntentionAction](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html) that available only if press `Alt+Enter` in an editor when a cursor set on an interface declaration.
In other words, expected behavior as in cases when the "Implement interface" intention action appears.

[image]

Place in an editor:

```
public interface SomeInterfaceNameDeclaration {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `IntentionAction.isAvailable()` method, you receive an `Editor` and a `PsiFile`. You can use `file.findElementAt(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset())` to find a PSI element at caret, and then `PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType()` to find an element of the type you need. See [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/navigating_psi.html) for more information.

Also, you can refer to the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/intention/impl/CreateSubclassAction.java) of the "Implement interface" action as an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the source code of the "Implement interface" action, it should really help!

Answer (score 0):

See the code sample [conditional_operator_intention](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/tree/master/code_samples/conditional_operator_intention) for an example of using the Psi Tree in `ConditionalOperatorConvertor.isAvailable()` to determine whether to enable or disable the intention action functionality.